# How to minimize iPhone App on button click action?

Tags: iphone, ios6, minimize

On button click I want my app to be minimize..

I try to use `exit()`,but apple reject application when  exit is being used.

What is the perfect solution for this?

Comment: Why do you want a button that minimize app, iPhone already have that button in hardware.

Comment: Also, `exit()` does not minimize your app. It terminates the app.

Comment: Actually i have a registration form in which there are two button Accept and Decline.On Accept button app goes forward and on Decline button client wants app to be exit.but when i use exit apple reject it.so i decide to minimize app that why searching solution for this?

Comment: Yes iMartin you are rite.exit terminates the app. Thats the reason Apple reject my iPhone Application.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ccnv/id574345063?mt=8    i download this app from apple app store,this application also having same form which i want to implement in my application.Registration form opens in it and having accept and cancel button.when tap on cancel button an alert pop up for yes or no.when tap on yes app exits..so how this app is on apple app store.same thing i want to do in my application

Comment: Presence of such app on App Store does not prove anything. If you report that app, they may block it from App Store.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are not allow do it without using the Home Button.
2. exit() will terminates the app.
3. Apple will surely reject your app if you achieve it anyhow.
4. Alternatively, take user to another screen. Don't minimize the app.
5. Quitting your application or sending it to the background programmatically is a violation of the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines]

Comment: but on which screen.As Registration Form is my First Screen in my App and there i have Accept and Decline Button.

Comment: Add one screen which says "It's necessary you accept the terms to proceed." Or, just a pop up. And keep user on the same page.

Comment: but is there any other way through which i can minimize my iPhone app

Comment: @user2131477 : No there's no other way. Your app will be rejected if you do this in your app.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ccnv/id574345063?mt=8    i download this app from apple app store,this application also having same form which i want to implement in my application.Registration form opens in it and having accept and cancel button.when tap on cancel button an alert pop up for yes or no.when tap on yes app exits..so how this app is on apple app store.same thing i want to do in my application

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for entering to the background.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ccnv/id574345063?mt=8    i download this app from apple app store,this application also having same form which i want to implement in my application.Registration form opens in it and having accept and cancel button.when tap on cancel button an alert pop up for yes or no.when tap on yes app exits..so how this app is on apple app store.same thing i want to do in my application

Comment: Does it enter _background (minimize) with animation_ or _terminates without animation_? As I said, there is no public API for entering background.